# How do I "update" a required file during the node process?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I have been trying to make a system with "memory". I used a JSON file for this, but it never refreshes the file. I looked it up and I got a function showing this

```
    function requireUncached(module) {
    delete require.cache[require.resolve(module)];
    return require(module);
}
```

but they didn't show any syntax. Do I only put it at the top instead of `const whatever = require(file)`? Do I do it in every function it needs to be refreshed in? I have no idea. The reason I need this is so that it is all automatic and I don't have to do **node .** every time.

Comment: If you want to be able to edit the JSON file at any time, instead of `const whatever = require(file)` at the top, you want to delete that line and replace every instance of `whatever` with `requireUncached(file)`. Keep in mind though that assigning to `whatever.prop = ...` doesn't write back to the JSON file, for that you'll need to use [`fs.writeFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) or similiar.

Comment: The easiest would be not to read JSON files with `require` but with `fs.readFile()`. The sophisticated way would be, having only one instance of your json object in memory  and wherever you need it, you just have a reference to that single instance. When you modify it, all references automatically see the updates (don't forget to write back to disk on modifications).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>Warning, using `Proxy` and `fs.writeFileSync()` is ***slow***</sub>

Here's a convenient function that uses a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy) to automatically write changes back to disk whenever the object in memory is updated:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const storage = (path, encoding = 'utf8', space = null) => {
  const object = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path, encoding));
  let immediate = null;
  const scheduleWriteFile = () => {
    clearImmediate(immediate);
    immediate = setImmediate(() => {
      fs.writeFileSync(path, JSON.stringify(object, null, space), encoding);
    });
  };
  const handler = {
    get(target, property) {
      const value = Reflect.get(target, property);
      if (Object(value) === value) {
        const descriptor = Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, property);
        if (descriptor === undefined || descriptor.configurable || descriptor.writable) {
          return new Proxy(value, handler);
        }
      }
      return value;
    },
    ...Object.fromEntries(['defineProperty', 'deleteProperty', 'set'].map(
      (key) => [key, (...args) => {
        const result = Reflect[key](...args);
        if (result) {
          scheduleWriteFile();
        }
        return result;
      }]
    ))
  };
  return new Proxy(object, handler);
};
```

Example usage:

```js
const settings = storage('config.json', 'utf8', 2);

...

// automatically schedules call to
// fs.writeFileSync('config.json', JSON.stringify(settings, null, 2), 'utf8')
// after updating object
settings.users[user.id].banned = true;
```

The advantage of using [`setImmediate()`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_args) is that if multiple properties are updated synchronously on `settings`, it only schedules one call to `fs.writeFileSync()`, and it will occur after the event loop processes currently pending I/O events.

Because the proxy object recurses, you can treat `settings` exactly as a normal object, keep variable references to object or array properties, and read primitive values from it as usual.

The only restriction is that the JSON file must begin with `{` or `[` in order for the object to be allowed as the target of a `Proxy`.